# Segmentation fault in QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth)

Tags: qt, segmentation-fault, qt6

I tried to query the pixelMetric of the current application style, but I got a segmentation fault in the following line of code:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    ** -->**    int width = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth, nullptr);        
}
```

I also added the required modules in CMake file as:

```
find_package(Qt6 6.2 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Gui Qml Quick Widgets)
target_link_libraries(be_2App PRIVATE
    Qt6::Core
    Qt6::Gui
    Qt6::Qml
    Qt6::Quick
    Qt6::Widgets
)
```

Comment: Have you constructed a `QApplication` object in your `main` function?

Comment: @m7913d the main.cpp does not contain QApplication object, rather it contains a QGuiApplication object

Comment: If you're using `Qt` widgets you need to use `QApplication` rather than `QGuiQpplication`.

Comment: @m7913d That's where i am confused I haven't tried to use in widget but it's still giving me this error

Comment: Can you run your code under a debugger and provide us with the backtrace at the offending line of code?  You appear to be using QtCharts which, as far as I recall, has dependencies on QtWidgets.

Comment: as i gave in the code above.when i try to step into 
     width = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth, nullptr);
i receive a dialog box saying the following:
The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

Signal name : 
SIGSEGV
Signal meaning : 
Segmentation fault

Comment: Sure, but what's the backtrace at that point?  i.e. how did it get there?  I also notice that you explicitly request linking with Qt6::Widgets in your CMakeLists.txt.  That in itself will almost certainly cause problems if you don't create a `QApplication`.

Comment: If you want to use `QApplication` methods, you should construct a `QApplication` object inside your main function. Otherwise, `QApplication::style()` will return a `nullptr`. Dereferencing it will result in the encountered segmentation fault.

Comment: Note that I edited your question to remove all irrelevant information and added a [mcve]. Please try to provide it yourself the next time you ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `QApplication` methods, you should construct a `QApplication` object inside your `main` function. Otherwise, `QApplication::style()` will return a `nullptr`. Dereferencing it will result in the encountered segmentation fault.

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv); // Use QApplication instead of QGuiApplication

    int width = QApplication::style()->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_TextCursorWidth, nullptr);        
}
```